# CaliburnMicro StackOverflowException when ActivateItem function is invoked

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have two VM - View (inherited from Screen) and Edit (inherited from Screen). View is used to display grid with data and Edit - add/edit new items into grid.

In my ShellViewModel I have the following code to activate View.

```
    public void WorkstationView()
    {
        this.ActivateItem(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WorkstationViewModel>());
    }
```

In WorkstationViewModel when user clicks on the Create button the following code is invoked

```
    public void CreateAction()
    {
        EditableObject = new WorkstationDto();
        TryClose(true);
    }
```

And there is a listener to Deactivated event property, see code below (InitViewModels is invoked in ShellViewModel constructor).

```
    private void InitViewModels()
    {
        #region Init

        WorkstationViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WorkstationViewModel>();
        WorkstationEditViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WorkstationEditViewModel>();

        #endregion

        #region Logic

        WorkstationViewModel.Deactivated += (o, args) => 
        {
            if (WorkstationViewModel.EditableObject == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            WorkstationEditViewModel.EditableObject = WorkstationViewModel.EditableObject;
            ActivateItem(WorkstationEditViewModel);
        };

        #endregion
    }
```

The problem here is a StackOverflow exception when I close Edit view (see create action).

Comment: There are several bad practices here, and some strange design decisions. Can you show your WorkstationEditViewModel EditableObject property?

Comment: You need to show the code as devdigital said, in general a SO exception usually means you've got some sort of infinite loop going on. In general this code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be, your ViewModels should compose implicitly not explicity. This is why the bootstrapper asks for the shell to activate, so that composition can happen without the need to access any given dependency container directly.

Comment: EditableObject is just a property of some type. Basically I am not pretending for such a design as a must. I just want to show edit dialog from Screen. Unfortunately I cannot call ActivateItem from it.

Answer (score 0):

“Since the Conductor does not maintain a “screen collection,” the activation of each new item causes both the deactivation and close of the previously active item.” [Caliburn.Micro documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2C%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)

If you are using `Conductor<T>`, then `ActivateItem(WorkstationEditViewModel);` inside of the `Deactivated` handler is implicitly re-triggering the deactivation of the previous viewmodel - giving you an infinite loop. Try changing your conductor to inherit from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive` instead. However, you will still have two deactivations: the one from the original TryClose operation, and a second one when you activate the new screen. Overriding `DetermineNextItemToActivate` can help you avoid that.